# query that compare prices from 2 tables and execute a message

Tags: java, sql-server

I am stuck for days i am trying to build a `sql query` that check if my products need to be order.... so that i want is one query that make the check

i have one table `Priority_lvl`  with `columns`  `Prio_level ,Prio_Number` that has already values inside   the `first  column` has  values  for exable 'law','medium'......and the `second column` has  numbers `'50','100'`

my second table `Products` with `columns Pro_Quantity`   has my product  capacity .  My other `column`  `Pro_Capa_level` has the value  of `Prio_level` that i have already insert with other query .

So i need a query that tells me if the column `Pro_Quantity` is less than `Prio_Number` depended each time for what `Pro_Capa_level` is the product ....

table `Priority_lvl`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Priority_lvl](
    [Prio_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Prio_level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Prio_Number] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

table `Products`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [Pro_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Price] [float] NULL,
    [Pro_Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Pro_Supplier_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pro_Tax] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Cat_products] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Pro_Capa_level] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Pro_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

here is my try but is awful

```
SELECT * FROM Products P INNER JOIN .Products ON   Products.Pro_Capa_level= Priority_lvl.Prio_level WHERE Pro_Capa_level = Prio_level  AND Pro_Quantity<=Prio_Number ;
```

and here is my execute

```
public ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> getproList()
     {
         ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> proList =new ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> ();
         Connection connection =getConnection();
           SELECT * FROM Products P INNER JOIN .Products ON   Products.Pro_Capa_level= Priority_lvl.Prio_level WHERE Pro_Capa_level = Prio_level  AND Pro_Quantity<=Prio_Number ;
         Statement stt;
         ResultSet rss;
         try{
            stt = connection.createStatement();
            rss = stt.executeQuery(query);
            Update_del_insert_products  update_del_insert_products ;
            while(rss.next())
            {
               update_del_insert_products = new Update_del_insert_products (rss.getString("Pro_Id"),rss.getString("Pro_Name"),rss.getString("Pro_Price"),rss.getString("Pro_Quantity"),rss.getString("Pro_Supplier_id"),rss.getString("Pro_Tax"),rss.getString("Cat_products"),rss.getString("Pro_Capa_level"));
               proList.add(update_del_insert_products);
            }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         return proList;
     }
```

Comment: Can you post the actual table schemas pls

Comment: Something's odd with the query.  Shouldn't this `Products P INNER JOIN .Products` be something like `Priority P INNER JOIN Products`?

Comment: i get message syntax error near Priority ...

Comment: No that this is an answer, but you should have had the Prio_Id as a FK in the Products table instead of the description and use that to join the two tables. Also, in the Where clause you can remove the Pro_Capa_level = Prio_level since that's what you are joining on.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Priority_lvl INNER JOIN Products ON   Products.Pro_Capa_level= Priority_lvl.Prio_level WHERE Pro_Capa_level = Prio_level  AND Pro_Quantity<=Prio_Number ;  somehow this works  ty Balkrishna Rawool !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM Priority_lvl INNER JOIN Products ON 
Products.Pro_Capa_level= Priority_lvl.Prio_level WHERE Pro_Capa_level = Prio_level 
AND Pro_Quantity<=Prio_Number ";
```